# Zend IMAP search and filters

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap

How do i make search using filters like in gmail. Like getting list of email with specific labels or list of mails from a specific email address. I couldn't able to find it in documentations.

Note:I use oAuth for authentication. I hope this has nothing to do with search.

Comment: any update on this? I want get messages in my inbox with date filter using Zend Oauth IMAP classes.

Comment: @Adnan You need to add a search function in a Zend Imap class. http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8858 See the answer below. You can use filters which you use in imap_search()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels on Gmail are in fact (from IMAP point of view) folders, so to get all emails with label you can just list e-mails in folder of this name.

To search you could use "undocumented" function `search()` (see `Zend/Mail/Imap/Protocol.php`), but see the method comment: `This method is currently marked as internal as the API might change and is not safe if you don't take precautions.` So you may rather use PHP's own [imap_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) function.

See also Zend Framework feature request [ZF-8858](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8858).

Comment: I had to go `Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php` and set `$_protocol` to `public`. Then `$mail->_protocol->search(array('ALL'));` worked for me.