# Can you use Google OAuth to search through users email?

Tags: php, email, authentication, oauth, gmail

I'm trying to create an application that uses Google OAuth for login, and then scans through the users email to see the last time they emailing certain people.

So the user logs in with Google OAuth, and then inputs johndoe@gmail.com --> I want to be able to search through their gmail to tell them the last time they spoke.

I can get "feeds" of their inbox, and other folders, but I can't find a way to query for an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access a user's mail with OAuth and the IMAP protocol. There is specifications on how to use the OAuth and IMAP combination on developers.google.com, check the links from here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

PHP has good support for the IMAP protocol: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php
You can use imap_search() in PHP for searching for messages with IMAP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php

Edit: Sorry, the PHP IMAP support does not work with OAuth. You should use the Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap, which has the functionality to authorize with an IMAP server using OAuth. Using the method `requestAndResponse`, it is possible to make an IMAP SEARCH request.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that Google OAuth page before. It only gives you access to "feeds." I have been using this, but it requires me to store the email/password for each user. `imap_open($gmailhostname,$gmailusername,$gmailpassword);` 
When I use this, I can get into the user inbox and search for specific items as IMAP is pretty robust. However, like I said, it requires me to store email/password, which is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too fast and careless. We are using Zend Mail at my company for this, however we are not doing searches, and that does not seem to be an implemented function in the Zend Mail classes, but it is possible, using the requestAndResponse() method, which you can use to build your own IMAP request.

Comment: Ah you're right. This all can be done with Zend. I saw this stackoverflow, and someone was doing a similar action. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894238/zend-imap-search-and-filters